# Sorting a file by two columns while retaining the header on output files with AWK command

Tags: sorting, awk, header

I want to sort a file with product and ID and I will get several files as output in awk. 
The command I'm using is

```
awk -F"|" 'NR>1 {print > "INITIATION_V1_"$1"_"$2".csv"}' test1.csv
```

But it doesn't keep header for me in every output files I got. I searched a lot in google and tried with `NR==1 ||` and `NR==1 ;` too but it doesn't work out for me. Anyone can help me in this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks miltonb for editing my question. I'm new in this field. Do you have any idea in solving my problem? Thank you.

Comment: @HengUnn, provide a minimal example input file and the corresponding expected output file (name *and* contents).

Comment: I want to split by column 1(product) and column 2(ID). For example, So everything for product=A and ID=1 will be in one file. And I want to keep the same header for each output files.

Comment: @GrishaLevit I got the answer already. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} 
                {file="INITIATION_V1_"$1"_"$2".csv";  
                 print (a[file]++?"":h ORS) $0 > file}' test1.csv
```

`a[file]++` is the line counter indexed by output filename, insert the header appended with ORS only before the first line, which will become the header for each split file.

Comment: It worked out exactly what I want for the output files. Thank you so much @karakfa ! I need some time to digest the code given by you. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Inian thanks for your help too. You guys are just too awesome and kind to help. It helps me to learn a lot. Hope to learn from you guys in future. Keep in touch.